# LxTerminal: Command not executed, but window opens

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, raspbian

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/lxterminal -e "mpv http://wdr-1live-live.icecast.wdr.de/wdr/1live/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3"
```

When i run it, the terminal window opens, but the command is not executed and there is no prompt. The only thing visible in that window is a not responding cursor.

Why isn't the command executed? On one of my raspbians the script runs flawlessly, but when i move it to another raspbian, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

(Cant comment yet) Maybe you forgot...

```
chmod +x yourshellscript.sh
```

...because above commands working on my debian based installation...

```
cat wdr.sh && (ls -Flap wdr.sh ; ./wdr.sh)
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/lxterminal -e "mpv http://wdr-1live-live.icecast.wdr.de/wdr/1live/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 knoppix knoppix 112 Jun 19 16:48 wdr.sh

#...and in lxterminal...

Playing: http://wdr-1live-live.icecast.wdr.de/wdr/1live/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (mp3 2ch 48000Hz)
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
A: 00:00:05 / 00:00:09 (60%) Cache:  3s+111KB
File tags:
 icy-title: 1LIVE Sophie Schramm und der Simone
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when i use

```
lxterminal -e
```

instead of

```
/usr/bin/lxterminal -e
```